# Idenitfy IC - ZJF AD 4274 - Onsemi

Tags: identification

Anyone have a clue what that could be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it could be a [FAN4274](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_onsemi-FAN4274IMU8X_C124467.pdf).

[image]
<sub>Source: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Operational-Amplifier_onsemi-FAN4274IMU8X_C124467.html</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous reply. Seems to be the FAN4274 op-amp. Suppliers often change the prefix of the part number if they are supplied under license to certain equipment manufacturers (sometimes it is to enable special stock holding for that part for one customer). I have experienced this many times.